# Dynamic width of an element which depends on the width of element beside

Tags: css, width

I have 2 elements beside each other by floating right and left.
the **right** element width is dynamic by padding of children elements which increase or decrease dynamically! but the **left** element is a simple *DIV*. I want it's width to change according to the **right** element width. how can it be done by CSS ?

example :

```
<div style="float:left"></div>
<div style="float:right;padding:5px 10px;">
    <a>child1</a> 
    <a>child2</a> 
    <a>child3</a> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve, but if I understand right:

- you have an area A in wich you are floating the `right` element with the 3 children
- the rest of area A you want to fill with the `left` element

Is this correct?

Well the easiest way would be to wrap an `inline-block` element around the `right` element, that represents the whole A area and the `right` element floats on the right side of this parent element. Then all properties you assign to parent are going to represent the area A that is not covered by the `right` element. For example background color:

```
    <div style="display:inline-block; width:100%; background-color:blue;">
    <div style="float:right; right:0; padding:5px 10px; background-color:yellow;">
        <a>child1</a> 
        <a>child2</a> 
        <a>child3</a> 
    </div>
    </div>
```

Here you can see the result on [jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rKQXJ/](http://jsfiddle.net/rKQXJ/)